# How to record context in logs when task is run by multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j2

In some circumstances , we will submit task into another threads, but it will be troublesome to pass some context into another thread and log in explicitly. Is there any easy way to do this.

we use log4j2 and sl4j, and I try using ThreadContext but I found it does not work.

```
Pattern :
[%level{length=15}] %date [%t]【%X{context}】【%X】[%logger:%line] >>> %msg%n"
```

code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("starting=====================================");
        ThreadContext.put("context", UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""));
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        for(int i = 0 ; i<5;i++) {
            int index=  i ;
            es.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    log.info("task in es {}", index);
                    return null;
                }

            });
        };

        for(int i = 0 ; i<5;i++) {
            int index=  i ;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    log.info("task in new thread  {}", index);
                }
            }).start();
        };



        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("ending=====================================");
        ThreadContext.remove("context");
        es.shutdown();
//

    }
```

output:

```
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,750 [main]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:26] >>> starting=====================================
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,835 [Thread-3]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:51] >>> task in new thread  2
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,835 [Thread-1]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:51] >>> task in new thread  0
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,835 [pool-2-thread-1]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:38] >>> task in es 0
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,835 [Thread-5]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:51] >>> task in new thread  4
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,835 [Thread-4]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:51] >>> task in new thread  3
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,836 [pool-2-thread-3]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:38] >>> task in es 2
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,836 [pool-2-thread-2]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:38] >>> task in es 1
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,836 [pool-2-thread-4]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:38] >>> task in es 3
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,836 [pool-2-thread-5]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:38] >>> task in es 4
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:18,836 [Thread-2]【】【{}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:51] >>> task in new thread  1
[INFO] 2019-07-03 17:57:19,834 [main]【ed65cef8478b499995f0bf95c8d71c20】【{context=ed65cef8478b499995f0bf95c8d71c20}】[com.oppo.finance.fundcenter.core.FundCenterMain:63] >>> ending=====================================
```

as we can see, the context only works in the original main thread, it can not be passed to either thread created by `new Thread` or created by `ExecutorService`

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation

```
The MDC is managed on a per thread basis. To enable automatic inheritance of copies of the MDC to newly created threads, enable the Log4j system property.
```

So set this property to true

```
-Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true
```

And child threads will  inhertis the context, and you don't have to manage context for each thread manually.

Second option is to avoid using log context at all(usually there is problem with the context inheritance in thread pools and executors), and you can differentiate the log threads via thread name.

you can set the thread name like this in you Runnable:

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("SPECIFIC_NAME");
```

Comment: This answer is the post's solution.

Answer (score 0):

log4j2, slf4j context is bound to `ThreadLocal`. you'll need to set the context for each thread manually